# Losing this reference in $scope.$on event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm registering the "$routeChangeSuccessEvent" from Angularjs by setting the callback function. When the event is raised I can not access my controllers instance by "this". The current this instance is unedfined.

My complete TypeScript Code:

```
export class Ctlr {

    static $inject = ["$rootScope","$route"];

    constructor(private $scope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
        this.Scope = $scope;
        this.Title = "";
        //this.Scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccessEvent", this.onRouteChangeStart);
        this.RegisterEvents();
        }
    private RegisterEvents(): void {
        this.Scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccessEvent",(event: ng.IAngularEvent, args: any) => {
        //this is undefined
            console.log(this);
        });
    }
    public Scope: ng.IScope;
    public Title: string;

    public onRouteChangeStart(event: ng.IAngularEvent, args: any) {
        //this is undefined
        this.Title = args.$$route.name);
    }

}
```

}

I'm able to get access of the Title property with:

```
 private RegisterEvents(): void {
        var ref = this.Title;
        this.Scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccessEvent",(event: ng.IAngularEvent, args: any) => {
            ref = args.$$route.name;
        });
    }
```

But that's not a real solution because angularJS doesn't update its view. It seems that I didn't catch the right reference. If thats not possible the whole angularjs events seems to be not useabel - that can't be possible?

I also didn't find any topic about this strange behavior. Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: Just a quick tip: `constructor(private $scope: ...)` means the `$scope` is placed in the object properties, so the `this.Scope = $scope;` is redundant. Just use `this.$scope`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope changes when a callback is fired, that is why `this` becomes undefined.

Your other example of doing:

```
var ref = this.Title;
```

Actually just creates a -copy- of `Title` as it is a primitive type (string). Which is why it didn't work either. Updating `ref` does not update `this.Title`.

The usual solution to this, is to start the definition as:

```
var vm = this;

...
private RegisterEvents(): void {
    this.Scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccessEvent",(event: ng.IAngularEvent, args: any) => {
    //this is undefined
        console.log(vm);
    });
}
```

So rather than using `this` everywhere, you would use `vm`. Note that `vm` can be named whatever you want. The important part is you capture a reference to `this` in a scope where `this` is what you want to use in a callback. This works because `this` is **not** a primitive type, as it is an object and rather than taking a copy, it takes a reference.

Your other option is to use `bind` which you can apply to any function, this function essentially tells JavaScript what `this` will equate to. E.g.

```
$scope.$on("SomeEventHere", someCallbackFunction.bind(this));
```

It's a matter of preference which you use here but generally I see people using the `var something = this;` method.

Comment: I'm using TypeScript v1.7 and I don't get undefined in this for the first code snippet :(

Answer (score 1):

That's because this always refers to it's parent which is now the function. So if you wanted you could do this:

```
private RegisterEvents(): void {
    var ref = this;
    this.Scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccessEvent",(event: ng.IAngularEvent, args: any) => {
        console.log(ref);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can rebind the this variable: 
    `this.Scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccessEvent",this.onRouteChangeStart.bind(this));`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other solutions, and using at least TypeScript v1.7, you can use this using a fat arrow like:

```
$scope.$on('some-event', () => { console.log('here `this` is not undefined'); });
$scope.$watch('foo.bar', (a,b) => { console.log('here too...'); }
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccessEvent', () => { console.log('here too...'); });
```

But, if you want to pass a reference to a function from the same class you have to use the `.bind(this)` notation:

```
$cope.$on('$routeChangeSuccessEvent', this.onRouteChangeStart.bind(this));
```